# How to read $\textbf{A}^{op}$ in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, pronunciation

Simple question, how does one pronounce the name of the category $\textbf{A}^{op}$, defined as the dual of the category $\textbf{A}$?

Reading it, I want to say $\textit{ay-opp}$ /e$ɪ$-$ɑ$p/.

Comment: I would just say "The dual (or opposite category) of $A$"

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Does that not just become cumbersome in a full discussion, or is it second nature enough that you don't notice?

Comment: Why not just "A-opposite"?

Comment: I have used *ay-opp* conversationally, and seem to have been understood, but I've only heard one or two other people say it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say ay-op,and I have mostly heard that. Maybe one says the opposite of A the first time, but then proceeds to forget about it and ay-op.